# Master Pages fail to recognize new controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, master-pages

So, from my experience, masterpages sometimes can lag when you do updates. This is not a new occurance, you make a change, you build, you go to test and the MasterPage is still looking for the old control.

Anyone have any tips/tricks they use when this happens? Usually it goes away after a while, but I don't have a while.

I am using VS 2008.

Comment: Is this in a dev environement or in VS using it's server?

Comment: in the dev environment on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three main options for forcing IIS to reload everything are

- If running from Visual Studio, close out the ASP.NET Development Server, which forces it to re-open with the next run
- Change the web.config file (forces an IISReset)
- Call IISRESET directly from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue.  Do you restart IIS after you build?  Are you building in place or publishing?  Is this a web app?

Try making a small change to the web.config file when you build and see if that helps. It will reset the server for you and basically make things new again. :)

Comment: I'm not restarting IIS, I'm building and testing on localhost while developing, not publishing. I will try bouncing the web config.

Comment: All this will do is stop and start the web application... it won't actually push any new content down to the browser if it is cached at the browser level.

Answer (score 0):

When testing in IE, I find I have to actually click the refresh icon, not simply go to the address bar and hit enter again (like in Firefox) to have IIS push the updated content to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I see something in my browser that is 'stale' I hit control-f5 which forces a full trip back to the server to retrieve everything. This always gets me the latest version of everything without having to restart iis, play with the web.config, etc.